# Javascript/Jquery to restrict input field to one decimal and numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

Below is what i have so far, the problem is it works for input and for paste but if you paste again it looks like its only working for the data copied from the paste action only, its not taking into account what is already in that field.

```
    $('#val00').on('input', function(){
        this.value = this.value
        .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')             // numbers and decimals only
        .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
        .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 2 digits after decimal
        console.log("ON INPUT "+mynum);
        mynum++;
    })

    $('#val00').on('paste', function(){
        this.value = this.value
        .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')             // numbers and decimals only
        .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
        .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 2 digits after decimal
        console.log("ON PASTE "+mynum);
        mynum++;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably posted this question too soon without spending enough time debugging. Just thought id share my solution.

```
    $('#val00').on('paste', function(){

        if (this.value !="") {
            this.value = ""
        }else{
        this.value = this.value
        .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')             // numbers and decimals only
        .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
        .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 2 digits after decimal
        console.log("ON INPUT "+mynum);
        mynum++;
        }
    })
```

Comment: When I'm testing this is doesn't seem to work at all -- I seem to be able to paste whatever I like into the input field unhindered. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nph/z9Lqqx1s/)